# WinError 10060 python connect python socket through router

Tags: python, sockets, ip, port, portforwarding

I tried setting up a TCP socket with Python, and it works totally fine as long as I'm in the same network. But my problem is that I can't get it to work if one of the devices isn't in the same network.

I already tried setting the bind IP to '0.0.0.0', and if I try connecting I get socket error 10060.  I think the problem probably has something to do with port-forwarding, but I don't know how to do it in Python.

Here is the code I used to test it, and I don't know how I get the public IP from my device in Python (not the `gethostbyname()` function, that only returns the private IP).

I hope you can help me.

Server.py

```py
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 5000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        while True:
            text = input("Enter text: ").encode("utf-8")
            send_msg(conn,text)
            echo = recv_msg(conn).decode("utf-8")
            print(echo)
```

client.py

```py
#HOST = '192.168.0.220'
HOST = 'x.x.x.x' #ip address of server
PORT = 5000`

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    while True:
        data = recv_msg(s)
        send_msg(s,data)


def send_msg(sock, msg):
    msg = struct.pack('>Q', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock):
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 8)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>Q', raw_msglen)[0]
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock: socket.socket, n):
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data
```

Comment: Look up "port forwarding". It's the same problem that people have when they want to play Minecraft with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown is fine. `bind()`'ing the server to `0.0.0.0` is typically the correct thing to do, that allows it to listen on all *local* IPs installed on its machine. Or, you can `bind()` it to the specific IP of the adapter that is connected to your network. Either way is fine.

On the client side, if the client is on the same network, it can `connect()` to the server's LAN IP, and all is well.

The problem comes when the client is *not* on the same network. That means the client simply cannot connect to your server *directly*.  There is no physical route to facilitate that connection.  So, to remedy that, you must setup a Port Forwarding rule in your LAN router.  You must open a public IP/Port on the router's WAN, and map it to the server's LAN IP/Port.  Then the client will be able to connect to the router's WAN IP/Port and let the router forward the packets to the server's LAN IP/Port, and vice versa.

If your router supports uPNP, your server code can setup this Port Forwarding programmably.  There are uPNP libraries available, or your OS may even have APIs for that.  Otherwise, your router admin must setup the Port Forwarding rule by hand.

To discover your router's WAN IP for the client to connect to, your server code can query an external site like https://whatismyip.com, or even query the router directly (if the router has an API for this purpose).  Otherwise, you should subscribe to a 3rd party Dynamic DNS service that assigns you a static hostname that the client can always connect to, and then your server code, or even the router itself, can update the IP for that hostname whenever the router's WAN IP changes.